# Select brother of parent element relative to 'this' then select children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If the user hovers over `Test` then the href attribute of the link in the ´ul´ list e.g. the link of google should be outputted. But i have no idea how i can access the `a` tag from `this`.

```js
$("ul.myul li:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(1)").on
(
  "mouseover",
  function()
  {
    $link = $(this).closest('a').attr("href");
    $("#output").html($link);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myul">
  <li>
    <div>
      <a href="www.yahoo.de">yahoo</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Foo</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="myul">
  <li>
    <div>
      <a href="www.google.de">google</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Test</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="myul">
  <li>
    <div>
      <a href="www.bing.de">bing</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Test</div>
  </li>
</ul>

<p id="output"></p>
```

I've already tried `find` and `closest` but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("ul.myul li:nth-child(2) div").on("mouseover",function(){
    $link = $(this).parent().prev('li').find('a').attr("href");
    $("#output").html($link);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myul">
  <li>
    <div>
      <a href="www.yahoo.de">yahoo</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Test</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="myul">
  <li>
    <div>
      <a href="www.google.de">google</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Test</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="myul">
  <li>
    <div>
      <a href="www.bing.de">bing</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Test</div>
  </li>
</ul>

<p id="output"></p>
```

1. Use .pareent() to get the li
2. Use .prev() to get the li of the anchor
3. Use find to get the anchor

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).parents('ul').find('a')` gives you all the links in the same UL.